# Interactive Cascading Prompt in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 parameters Country as TextBox and State as DropDown. Country parameter asks user to enter value manually and based on that Country entered the State Parameter gets populated.

But, After entering the text in Country it is required to press enter or view report button by which I am getting an error first (Please select a value for parameter State) and then the State parameter is getting populated.

[image]

Is there any way to do this without pressing enter or clicking on view report? OR Pressing enter without error prompt(Please select a value for parameter State).

Comment: Why not make country as a drop down also?

Comment: Don't believe there is. (Also, second the previous comment :D.)

Comment: My actual scenario is not Country and State. For Example, say it is MovieNamePart and MovieNameFull. The list of MovieNameFull can be huge (say in Lacs) and I do not remember the full name of the movie. So, here I want to populate MovieNameFull like '%MovieNamePart%'.

Comment: Is there any way to handle such huge volume of data in Dropdown? Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do more with SSRS parameters than they were intended for.

The cleanest solution would be to build a "searching" report that would use the `MovieNamePart` parameter and display a list of all of the matching movie titles.

You would then put an action on the text which would open the other report and pass the full name of the movie.

---

Alternatively you could just bring in all the info about the movie as well and have it displayed as a collapsed section under each name. The user would then have access to all of the information about all of the matching movies without needing to load another report.